# Do I need to hurt zombies or kill them to level up my weapons?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I'm having a tricky time upgrading the Vesper in the Zombies gamemode, seeing as it's a hit-marker machine. I was wondering, do I just need to hurt zombies with the Vesper to get experience on the gun, or do I actually need to kill them? I would think I'd have to kill them, since I don't get player experience until I get a kill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, only getting kills and assists is when you will see the progression of the weapon increase.  This seems to hold true across the Call of Duty series, and the Wiki also states this in the [Black Ops 3 section](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_Level#Call_of_Duty:_Black_Ops_III):

> Weapons are leveled up through usage, such as getting kills or assists.

Though it says "usage," I've never once seen one of my weapons level up from just getting hit boxes.  The Vesper is a rather weak gun as you've said.  You can (as I'm sure you know) buff the weapon by pack-a-punching it.  <s>Once you reach level 11 with the gun, you can also equip FMJs for more damage.</s>

Comment: You get in game points per hit, but points only contribute to the gun once you secure a kill.

Comment: Pack a Punch is a good idea, I'm using an insta kill gobblegum and waiting for line ups. And you said level 11 one can equip FMJ? How? I don't see any attachment option, and as far as I know you can only PaP to get FMJ.

Comment: @ExoMute Maybe that's for online only? The [wiki page](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Vesper#Attachments) for the gun is where I got that information.  It also says PaP version has it like you said.  For now I'll strikeout that bit of text.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about. I think that section is apart from Zombies, I think it's meant for MP, which is confusing as to why they'd put it where it is.

Comment: To add to this, Insta-Kill XP all around is reduced, as well as Headshot XP.